# Как создать экземпляр класса с непостоянными параметрами?

Tags: python, ооп

Есть класс:

```
class Enemy():
""" Противники """
def __init__(self, name, lvl):
    """ Описание свойств монстра """
    self.name = name
    self.lvl = lvl

def printEnemyParam(self):
    print ("Монстр " + str(self.name) + " напал на тебя, у него " + str(self.lvl) + " уровень")

def printEnemyHp(self):
    print("У " + str(self.name) + " осталось " + str(self.hp) + " жизней")

def enemyChar(self):
    self.name = rand.choice(enemyName)
    self.lvl = rand.randint(1, 3)
```

Есть кортеж с именами:

```
enemyName = ("Злая бабка", "Трудовик", "Сосед Валера", "Социальный педагог", "Гопник Олег")
```

Я пытаюсь создать экземпляр этого класса, но не могу понять как из метода enemyChar() вытащить и поместить в экземпляр готовые результаты random'а

```
Enemy1 = Enemy(enemyChar() тут имя, enemyChar() а тут лвл)
```

И никак не могу понять как это можно сделать?

Comment: у вас нарушение зоны ответственности. `Enemy` должен отвечать за себя, а не за своё создание. Созданием должен заниматься другой класс

Comment: @ArchDemon почему вы так считаете? Класс может и должен создавать экземпляры этого класса (объекты). На то у него есть метод `__new__()`. Какой же класс, по-вашему, должен создавать объекты этого класса?

Comment: @АлексейР, некоторый экземпляр другого класса, который управляет противниками. Так рекомендуют нам шаблоны проектирования и принципы программирования , в частности, SOLID

Answer (score 0):

Нужно все-таки определиться - вы передаете в конструктор класса наименование и уровень монстра или же они генерятся рандомно при создании объекта. Если они должны генериться, то можно так - вызываете метод `enemyChar()` из инита. Тогда передавать аргументы в конструктор бессмысленно.

```
class Enemy():
    """ Противники """
    enemyName = ("Злая бабка", "Трудовик", "Сосед Валера", "Социальный педагог", "Гопник Олег")

    def __init__(self):
        """ Описание свойств монстра """
        super().__init__()
        self.enemyChar()

    def printEnemyParam(self):
        print("Монстр " + str(self.name) + " напал на тебя, у него " + str(self.lvl) + " уровень")

    def printEnemyHp(self):
        print("У " + str(self.name) + " осталось " + str(self.hp) + " жизней")

    def enemyChar(self):
        self.name = rand.choice(self.enemyName)
        self.lvl = rand.randint(1, 3)
        self.hp = 5


Enemy1 = Enemy()
Enemy1.printEnemyParam()
Enemy1.printEnemyHp()
```

```
Монстр Злая бабка напал на тебя, у него 3 уровень
У Злая бабка осталось 5 жизней
```

И поскольку `enemyChar()` вызывается однократно только при создании объекта, можно все это реализовать в `__init__()`

Comment: def __init__(self):
        """ Описание свойств монстра """
        super().__init__()
        self.enemyChar()

super() Для чего нужен? Я думал что этот метод нужен только для классов наследников? 

Спасибо вам за помощь. Вы очень мне помогли.

Comment: [В Python все классы неявно наследуются от базового класса object. Это значит, что даже если при создании класса явно не указывать его родителя, он все равно будет наследовать от object.](https://sky.pro/media/nasledovanie-ot-object-v-python/)